# How to create elements such as text within a div from the data entered a html form including an uploaded image?

Tags: javascript, html

I want the elements within a div to be created using a html form. The user will fill out a title, select an amount to spend and upload an image. On click the form's submit button I want these entered details to become the elements within the offer_display div. The form and the offer_display div are on the same page. I want to create a javascript function that pushes this info or stores the info in a variable that can be used in the display div.

```
<body>
<div class="form">
Form <br><br>
<form name="input" action="javascript:alert(titleValue);">

Title: <input type="text" name="title" class="titleInsert">

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

</div>

<div class="offer_display">

  <div class="title" id= title></div>

</div>

</body>

<script>
var titleValue="";
$('#titleInsert').on("change", function () {
titleValue=$(this).val();
$("#title h3").text("titleValue");
});

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: maybe some examples of your js code? what you've tried so far? fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery and give `id` to the fields and form elements. then capture and store the values in a variable using selectors `onchange` then u can use it anywhere you want.

```
var titleValue="";
$('#titleId').on("change", function () {
  titleValue=$(this).val();
});
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: Thank you, in the div offer_display. How would I replaced for example <h3> Title <h3> with the variable titleValue?

Comment: In offer_display also give `id` for elements and use 
`$("#titleDivId h3").text("New Header Text");`

Comment: I simplified the code above. I'm still having no issues could you explain my mistakes

Comment: It should be `id="titleInsert"` not `class="titleInsert"` and do not use quotes for `titleValue` use `.text(titleValue);`